# $_COOKIE shows cookie, INSPECT doesnt! why?

Tags: cookies

Can anyone tell me why Firebug INSPECT doesnt display cookies, while they are displayed with `$_COOKIE`?

[image]

I use:

`setcookie($name,$value,time()+999999, '/wp/3/',null,null,true);`

Comment: You need to show the code that sets the cookie

Comment: @JAAulde thanks, question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `true` as the 7th parameter to `setcookie`. Per the [`setcookie` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), the 7th parameter is the `$httponly` parameter. When set to true, it makes the cookie accessible *only* via HTTP, and nothing else--including scripts.

**Quote:**

> **httponly**
>
> When TRUE the cookie will be made accessible only through the HTTP protocol. This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. It has been suggested that this setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers), but that claim is often disputed. Added in PHP 5.2.0. TRUE or FALSE

You wither need to pass that as `false`, or omit it (since the function defaults this optional parameter to `false`.)

Comment: but insecpt should have shown that anyway (even with `httpOnly` flag)

Comment: @TazoTodua Inspect shouldn't have shown it, AFAIK, because that's all done by JS. Going to the browser preference and asking it to show cookies for a site should show it, though.